# MySQL "Insert ... On Duplicate Key" with more than one unique key

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

I've been reading up on how to use MySQL insert on duplicate key to see if it will allow me to avoid Selecting a row, checking if it exists, and then either inserting or updating.  As I've read the documentation however, there is one area that confuses me. This is what the documentation says:

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row is performed

The thing is, I don't want to know if this will work for my problem, because the 'condition' I have for not inserting a new one is the existence of a row that has two columns equal to a certain value, not necessarily that the primary key is the same.  Right now the syntax I'm imagining is this, but I don't know if it will always insert instead of replace:

```
INSERT INTO attendance (event_id, user_id, status) VALUES(some_event_number, some_user_id, some_status) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status=1
```

The thing is, event_id and user_id aren't primary keys, but if a row in the table 'attendance' already has those columns with those values, I just want to update it. Otherwise I would like to insert it. Is this even possible with ON DUPLICATE? If not, what other method might I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were you, I would make a primary key out of event_id and user_id. That will make this extremely easy with `ON DUPLICATE`.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39957/1)

```
create table attendance (
    event_id int,
    user_id int,
    status varchar(100),
    primary key(event_id, user_id)
);
```

Then with ease:

```
insert into attendance (event_id, user_id, status) values(some_event_number, some_user_id, some_status)
on duplicate key
update status = values(status);
```

Comment: what is "primary key(event_id, user_id)" doing? Does it generate a primary key from that?

Comment: It makes the pair of event_id and user_id your primary key. So if you are inserting with the same event_id AND user_id it will update, otherwise it will insert. ONLY if they BOTH match, not just event_id or just user_id. I added an SQLFiddle so you can check it out.

Comment: so it doesn't add an extra physical column?

Comment: Not that you will get from a query, no. It is just telling the table to use the combination of the event_id column and the user_id column as the key, instead of just a single column.

Answer (score 8):

The quote includes "a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index".  So, your values do not need to be the primary key:

```
create unique index attendance_eventid_userid on attendance(event_id, user_id);
```

Presumably, you want to update the existing record because you don't want duplicates.  If you want duplicates sometimes, but not for this particular insert, then you will need another method.

Comment: in the answer below, Chad used a primary key in a similar way. Could I make a unique index without creating another column in the same way that he did below?

Comment: You can create either a unique index or a primary key on the columns.  Because almost all tables I create have an auto-incremented primary key, I would use a unique index.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to write a trigger that checks if the pair (event_id, user_id) exists in the table before inserting, and if it exists just update it.

Answer (score 1):

To the broader question of "Will `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE` respect a UK even if the PK changes", the answer is yes: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c7723/1)

In this SQLFiddle I insert a new record, with a new PK id, but its values would violate the UK. It performs the ON DUPLICATE and the original PK id is preserved, but the non-UK `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` value changes.