# Update data in mysql column field without removing previous value

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update "new" column value with new value but problem is my query remove previous data while inserting new value

What is want: here is example table structure,

Table name = agg_lvl primary key set = uid

```
uid     | new
--------|--------
1       | 100
2       | 300
```

You can see "new" has 100 points, for example I send 100 new points to user 1, so new column value should be 100 + 100 = 200, right now with this code

```
$query4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO agg_lvl (uid, new) VALUES ('$uid','$new')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uid='$uid',new='$new'");
```

Not sure what

```
new = '$new'
```

I have tried both ways but no success = >

```
new = 'new + $new' or new = new + '$new'
```

Comment: 2nd: `new=new+$new` exectly = `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new=new+$new`

Comment: near miss :( so the problem was because of '' i remove it as per your instructions and now able to get my desire results

Comment: please post an answer, in comments i have no control to accept your answer, i am asking this because your answer is perfect and credit should gone to where it due, so it's due on you

Comment: i am back to computer and writing the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make changes in your query

1. Make `num = nun+$num` to add new value to old one
2. Remove quotes arount $new because it is a number but not a string
3. Remove uid from set list because insert already point to that record

And your query should look so:

```
$query4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO agg_lvl (uid, new) VALUES ('$uid','$new')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new=new+$new");
```

Comment: one new and strange thing happened

Comment: could you a little bit more?

Comment: it's working Perfect, one new and strange thing happened, the problem is since "id" i set Auto Increment and primary key, so when this query fire, it inserting new row every-time, the reason is " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  " not working, because of " KEY " case, do you have any idea about how to deal with should i need to assign unique name to column " date " so we able to update row if date is same, if yes than how ? so we have total 4 columns in db , ( id, uid, new, date )

Comment: what is uid in this case?

Comment: uid is coming from form posting

Comment: i found something here, but not sure how to use in my case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749516/mysql-insert-on-duplicate-key-with-more-than-one-unique-key

Comment: **i am getting results like this**  id is key here and i set it auto-increment:

Comment: id   |  uid  |   new  |  date

Comment: --------|------|---------|----------------

Comment: 100  |   1   | 100    | 2016-05-18

Comment: 99   |   1   | 100    | 2016-05-18

Comment: **while i want results like this**

Comment: id   |  uid  |   new  |  date

Comment: -------|-------|---------|----------------

Comment: 99  |   1   |   200   | 2016-05-18

Answer (score 0):

Okay first i will answer with the proper way to do the same, In this case i am assuming that UID is unique, so you make a new table `scorecard` with UID as foreign key. Now rather than update, you just insert stuff to table like if UID 1 gains 10 and 20 points, there are two entries. onw with 10 and one with 20. Now to get his current points, you add all points where UID=1 .

Now in your implementation the correct query would be

`UPDATE userData SET points = points + x WHERE UID = $uid`

where x is the new points gained and `points` is the name of column

Comment: @Rahul thanks for the catch, happened because i added the where statement in an edit and forgot to check the syntax again :)

Comment: 2nd: new=new+$new exectly = ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new=new+$new – splash58, this answer is working for me now

Comment: @Goarge Go and why have you accepted not the answer that give you the result ? :)  Accept your one

Comment: because the guy who answer send comments he didn't posted answer, i guess he is new here

Comment: when i try to accept my answer it says " accept your own answer in next 2 days ?

Answer (score 0):

$query4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO agg_lvl (uid, new) VALUES ('$uid','$new')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uid='$uid',new=new+$new");

worked for me with help of @splash58