# mysql update data entry in column without removing previous data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I'm trying to achieve is whenever this column is updated, it shouldn't remove the previous data that has been filled, instead, it should just enter data in the next line with the previous data too.

For example

- Author 1
- Author 2

This is my code

```
$booktb = $db->update("books", "author" => $author);
```

I've looked into this question but it didn't work for me
[Update data in mysql column field without removing previous value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964608/update-data-in-mysql-column-field-without-removing-previous-value)

Comment: It sounds like you want `insert`, not `update`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff nop didn't work for me, it stopped even updating the column before it was just overwriting the new data.

Comment: May be you want  `select` an author ,  change some field value  and `insert` a new author ?

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code

```
$b = $db->select("books","author" => "kafka"); 

$b["title"] =  "another book"

$db->insert("books",$b);
```